# How can I display Chinese characters in Apache's directory listing?

Tags: apache-2.2

For example:

When you go to this website, it shows weird characters instead of Chinese characters in the Apache directory listing:

http://helloziyie.info/info

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be because your server is returning a 8-bit character set as reported by the response headers to be [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

```
Date: Thu, 24 Sep 2009 08:52:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Chinese characters are multi-byte characters. Googling for "apache charset chinese" or similar yields a number of different methods to instruct Apache to return multi-byte characters.